# Ansible hot add multiple ports

Tags: ansible

Ansible Playbook

How to add multiple ports (interactive prompt)  using firewall-cmd command in ansible-playbook

```
vars_prompt:  
   - name: port
     prompt: "Enter port#"
     private: no
```

I can do for one port but not multiple ports

Answer (score 0):

`vars_prompt` "loops" are not possible (as of Ansible 2.3) without writing custom plugins.

You can workaround this by expecting comma-separated string and split it later into list:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
    - name: ports
      prompt: "Enter port(s) number"
      private: no
  tasks:
    - name: add port
      shell: /bin/firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port={{ item }}/tcp
      with_items: "{{ ports.split(',') }}"
```

Comment: Enter ports number: 2041,2042 failed: msg: ports is undefined not working

Comment: vars_prompt:
     - name: port
       prompt: "Enter ports number"
       private: no
   tasks:
     - debug:
         msg: "Do smth for port {{ item }}"
       with_items: "{{ ports.split(',') }}"
     - name: add port
       shell: /bin/firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port={{ port }}/tcp
FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/bin/firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=2040,2041/tcp"

Comment: You should do `firewall-cmd` inside a loop, as I showed with `debug` module.

Comment: Please let me how do I use loop in same yaml file. can you give me example.